# Strange error with Android Studio selection

Tags: android-studio

[image: My selection error]

Hello.

I'm having trouble selecting text in Android Studio.

This happens whenever I select any text in any kind of editor (Java, Groovy, XML).

When this happens, I cannot: type text, use the 'delete' key on the text, or any other modifications.

I noted the white box, which usually indicates the 'insert' function. *But* I am on a MacBook Air, and there is no 'insert' key on the keyboard!

I'm using Android Studio 2021.2.1 Beta 2.

Any help would be appreciated, I've scoured the menus, even tried going back a 'Preview' version, but nothing has helped. I do not believe this is a System wide setting, Pages and other apps do not have this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error was fixed by disabling Vim plugin